# react select creatable (not clearable)

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I use multi select input with react select creatable, the problem i can't clear what user write for any items or for all, i tried with isClearable={true}, but nothing change.
for select input with options it work's correctly
any help please

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Creatable from 'react-select/creatable'

const Register = props => {
  const [tagInputValue, setTagInputValue] = useState('')
  const [tagValue, setTagValue] = useState('')

  const handleChange = (field, value) => {
    switch (field) {
      case 'roles':
        setRoleValue(value)
        break
      default:
        break
    }
  }

  const handleKeyDown = event => {
    if (!tagInputValue) return
    switch (event.key) {
      case 'Enter':
      case 'Tab':
        setTagValue([...tagValue, createOption(tagInputValue)])
        setTagInputValue('')

        event.preventDefault()
        break
      default:
        break
    }
  }

  const createOption = label => ({
    label,
    value: label
  })

  const handleInputChange = (value) => {
    setTagInputValue(value)
  }
  return (
    <div className='container'>
          <Creatable
            isClearable={true}
            isMulti
            components={{ DropdownIndicator: null }}
            inputValue={tagInputValue}
            menuIsOpen={false}
            onChange={(value) => handleChange('tags', value)}
            placeholder=''
            onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
            onInputChange={handleInputChange}
            value={tagValue}
          />
        </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a CreatableSelect and changing your handleChange method.

```
import CreatableSelect from 'react-select/creatable';


const handleChange = (value, actionMeta) => {
    console.group('Value Changed');
    console.log(value);
    console.log(`action: ${actionMeta.action}`);
    console.groupEnd();
    setTagValue(value)
    }
```

Then in your CreatableSelect will look like this:

```
                <CreatableSelect
                  isClearable
                  isMulti
                  components={{ DropdownIndicator: null }}
                  inputValue={tagInputValue}
                  menuIsOpen={false}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  placeholder="Type an employee and press enter"
                  onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                  onInputChange={handleInputChange}
                  value={tagValue}
                />
```